# How can I make multiple WebAPI?

Tags: asp.net, angular, .net-core, asp.net-web-api

I want to upgrade my projects from asp.net mvc to asp.net core with angular 12.So far I have alot of projects such as "E-training", "E-library", and so on. Do I need multiple web API projects for each project or combine all with only single web api projects?

Comment: It depends on your projects and definitely it takes a lot of time to analyze and choose the approach that is the best for your projects, your company or even your situation. this article could help you: https://www.n-ix.com/microservices-vs-monolith-which-architecture-best-choice-your-business/

Comment: are these projects already different APIs or part of same API ?

Comment: Can I make microservice architecture with only 1database and alot of tables and relationships?

Comment: @CodingMytra different api, because i want to make it multi-page webapp with single authentication

Answer (score 0):

You don't **HAVE TO**. You can do whatever you want but it's better to seperate them if they're not related in my opinion.